# How to implement async pipe using Custom DataType

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and have been developing an application of my own to enhance my skill.During this process i came across async pipes but am having some difficulty implementing them for Custom types .
Code Shown below:-

header-model.ts

```
export class HeaderData
{
    flag:boolean=false;
    loggedInName:string='';

    constructor(f,n)
    {
        this.flag=f;
        this.loggedInName=n;
    }
}
```

header-navigation-service.ts:-

```
 export class NavigationService
{
private loggedIn=new BehaviorSubject<HeaderData>(new HeaderData(false,''));

get isLoggedIn()
{
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
}

 login(val:HeaderData)

{
    if(val.flag==true)
    {
        console.log('In service -> '+val);
        const val1=new HeaderData(val.flag,val.loggedInName);
        this.loggedIn.next(val1);
    }
}
}
```

I have a Login Component which checks if the UserCredentials are valid and sets the Login method(flag=true,loggedInName=username) in header-navigation-service.

header.component.ts:-

```
showHeader:HeaderData;
  ngOnInit() {

    this._headerNavigation.isLoggedIn.subscribe((data:HeaderData)=>
  {
this.showHeader=data;

  });


  }
```

Right Now im subscribing to the isLoggedIn(), but i dont want to subscribe to it, since im not manipulating the data, rather i just want to make use of Angular async to retrieve the data and display in my view.

Comment: Well, do it, and if something doesn't work as you expect, post the relevant code, tell precisely what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation looks good. You just need to make couple of changes.

> 1. Just use Obserable variable in header component

```
  isLoggedIn$; // Observable variable will be used by async.

  ngOnInit() {
      this.isLoggedIn$ = this._headerNavigation.isLoggedIn;
  }
```

> 2. Use of Observable variable isLoggedIn$ in HTML

```
<span>{{isLoggedIn$ | async}}</span>
```

> 3. Change in login function

```
login(val:HeaderData) {
      console.log('In service -> '+val);
      const val1=new HeaderData(val.flag,val.loggedInName);
      this.loggedIn.next(val1);
}
```

Comment: I tried using your approach, it prints  [Object, Object], 
, when i try to write :->  <span>{{isLoggedIn$.flag | async}}</span>, It doesnt give me any o/p or error.

Comment: Just put the `subscribe` function and check what value you are getting. There could be two cases. First, there is no value is setting. Second, login function is not being called. I had changed the login function in the answer.

Comment: I have tried with the subscribe function (as shown above in header.component.ts ), it works perfectly fine, i am getting all the data and am able to output it on  my html page, the problem is arising when i am not explicitly providing the subscribe function

Comment: There was issue in Answer changed `this.isLoggedIn = this._headerNavigation.isLoggedIn;` to `this.isLoggedIn$ = this._headerNavigation.isLoggedIn;`

Comment: Yeah, i realized that, the first time , but never the less it still isnt working